# How to Optimize a Trained Frozen Model for Inference?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, object-detection, inference

My goal is to decrease the size and complexity of a pre-trained Model (a Tensorflow Frozen Graph as Protobuf .pb file) as far as possible to make Inference (in my case realtime object detection using Webcams) as fast as possible.
(See my project repo for more information: https://github.com/GustavZ/realtime_object_detection)

Let's take a look at the pre-trained ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco provided by the tensorflow object detection API:
[link to ssd_mobilenet graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVNSA.png)

Which Layers are not necessary for inference (so only for the already completed training) and thus can be removed (from the config file to export a new frozen model using the `export_inference_graph.py` script)?

It would be very nice to get a general answer on how to optimize Models for inference as well as an answer on my special case as I think this could be of interest for others.

EDIT: I know now about the `optimize_for_inference.py` script provided py tensorflow. But i have no experience using it, for example how do i know which are the really necessary Input and Output nodes, or how do i read them from tensorboard?

Comment: did you figure that out ? I'm trying to do the same thing